# changing img using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image and some text in a `div`:

```
            <div id="quote">
                <div id="quote-picture">
                    <img src="tom.jpg">
                </div>
                <div id="quote-text">
                    <p>Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I attempt to change the image source with the onload function after changing the text it doesn't work. How can I change the image?

```
    $(document).ready(function($) { 
        $("#quote-text p").text("Hello World!");    
        $('img').attr('src', 'ben.jpg');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img').attr('src', 'ben.jpg');
```

I recommend you add a class/id to the IMG element and use that when selecting.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the img src. Try this:-

```
$("#quote-picture img").attr('src', 'ben.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
$("#quote-picture img").attr("src", "ben.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/XgVU9/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#quote-text p").text("Hello World!");
    $('#quote-picture img').attr('src', 'ben.jpg');
});
```

Comment: What difference would this make?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#quote-picture img').attr('src', 'ben.jpg');
```